# Can anyone explain what the second black wire is for?

Tags: wiring, garage

I am trying to replace the light switch in my garage with an occupancy sensor switch. When I opened the switchbox, I found no ground wire (rest of the house has neutral and ground in all the boxes I have opened) which is understandable. What is puzzling me is the two black wires attached to the bottom lug of the switch. Apart from being a code violation, what is the extra black wire doing?

[image: Garage light switch]

Comment: Anything else obvious on that circuit? What is the white wire doing back there? Conduit or romex?

Comment: Are there two white wires in the box? Could be that at the lower connection one black is the line hot for this switch and the other takes the line hot to another box. If so, the single black at the upper screw would be the switched hot for this switch.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate it's a conduit. I don't know why they ran the neutral. TBH, I can't understand what they are doing here.

Comment: @JimStewart there is only one white wire in the box. But, I think you have the right idea about the two black wires. I guess my only option is to just pigtail it with the new switch and leave the rest as is.

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks squarely into the back of the box please?

Comment: Do you have a testing device to see which wires are hot?

Answer (score 2):

The "extra" wire is the power wire that is feeding through the box. In one side and out to another device. The wire at the top is a switch leg. What's confusing me is the neutral. Is it just the angle of the photo and not showing it to feed through also?

Or is the top wire on the switch the power and the switch is feeding lamps in two locations? Once again why doesn't the neutral feed through?

Or maybe the neutral is just feeding down from a junction box as an afterthought.